# Viewing a mms:// live broadcast on my Desktop?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to view an upcoming live broadcast on my MacBook Pro The URL is mms://media.citris.berkeley.edu/webcast

I am only familiar with MMS with use on Mobile Phones, not desktops.

Is there a desktop application which can view the MMS protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html)

You can also take a look at the [VLC features list](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html).

[image]